# Can I have a separate delete permission for Plone content?

Tags: python, plone

I wish to create a separate permission, wherein in the 'sharing' tab, I would like to have a separate 'delete' permission along with the add, edit,review and view permissions. The user with only 'edit' permission should not be able to 'delete' and vice-versa.
I am using plone 4.1

Comment: Note about terminology: The Sharing tab controls roles, not permissions. Roles contain a set of permissions, needed to be able to perform that role. Thus, the `Editor` role has all the permissions needed to edit content, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The Plone has a separate permission for delete, but not role for it.

This is the outline of the process:

Remove Delete content from Editor role in the portal root in ZMI security tab.

Create a new local role "Deleter".

Give this role a Delete permission in the portal root.

Edit Sharing tab to show your new role (Not sure how, here is Plone 3.x solution http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.sharingroles )

Comment: @Mikko Ohtamaa http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.sharingroles is not compatible with plone 4.1, is there any other package to do the same ?

Comment: Not far as I know. I suggest you try 1) contact collective.sharingroles author 2) customize sharing page hard way, as you would do with any view overrides